# How to reduce space between selectInput and numericInput

Tags: html, css, shinydashboard

I have managed to code the following with Shinydashboard.
Is there any way to reduce

1. space between selectInput and numericInput as shown?
2. vertical space between "type" and "interval" selectInput?
3. narrow the height of menuItem "Charts"

A solution with adjustment to CSS would be good.  Thank you.

[image]

Code:

```
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Simple board"),
    dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "S",
    menuItem("Charts",  tabName = "V", icon = icon("database","fa-lg")),
    h5(div(style="display:inline-block;width:50%;text-align: left;",
        selectInput("Q", label = "type", choices = c("A","B","C"))),
       div(style="display:inline-block;width:50%;text-align: left;", 
        numericInput("NT", "Num", 15, min = 10, max = 33)),
        selectInput("s2", label = "interval", choices = c("17 mins","38 
min","124 mins"))
            )
        )
    ),
dashboardBody()
)
server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Share a working so we can take a look in code

Comment: How can we answer if you don't show us your code?

Comment: My bad.  Here is the MCVE:

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the help of `margin` property. 
For example, for selectInput, you can set `margin-left:5px` or so.

Similarly for interval input, you can set `margin-bottom:5px` for the div just above it.

You can also set negative value for `margin` property.

I hope this might help.

Comment: Nope, its not working.  Thanks for the answer.  I have provided MCVE.